# How to reach the service running in docker container(overlay) externally from different hosts

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, docker, hadoop-yarn

I have a docker container running on overlay network. My requirement is to reach the service running in this container externally from different hosts. The service is bind to container's internal IP address and doing port bind to host is not a solution in this case.

**Actual Scenario**:

The service running inside container is **spark driver** configured with **yarn-client**. The spark driver binds to container internal IP(10.x.x.x). When spark driver communicates with hadoop yarn running on different cluster, the **application master on yarn** tries to communicate back to spark driver on the driver’s container internal ip but it can’t connect driver on internal IP for obvious reason.

**Please let me know if there is a way to achieve the successful communication from application master(yarn) to spark driver(docker container).**

Swarm Version: 1.2.5

```html
docker info:

Containers: 3
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 42
Server Version: swarm/1.2.5
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, containerslots, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 1
 ip-172-30-0-175: 172.30.0.175:2375
  └ ID: YQ4O:WGSA:TGQL:3U5F:ONL6:YTJ2:TCZJ:UJBN:T5XA:LSGL:BNGA:UGZW
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 3 (2 Running, 0 Paused, 1 Stopped)
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 16
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 66.06 GiB
  └ Labels: kernelversion=3.13.0-91-generic, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, storagedriver=aufs
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-09-10T05:01:32Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.12.1
Plugins:
 Volume: 
 Network: 
Swarm: 
 NodeID: 
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address: 
Security Options:
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-91-generic
Operating System: linux
Architecture: amd64
CPUs: 16
Total Memory: 66.06 GiB
Name: 945b4af662a4
Docker Root Dir: 
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
```

Command to run container: I am running it using docker-compose:

```html
zeppelin:
    container_name: "${DATARPM_ZEPPELIN_CONTAINER_NAME}"
    image: "${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/zeppelin:${DATARPM_ZEPPELIN_TAG}"
    network_mode: "${CONTAINER_NETWORK}"
    mem_limit: "${DATARPM_ZEPPELIN_MEM_LIMIT}"
    env_file: datarpm-etc.env
    links:
      - "xyz"
      - "abc"
    environment:
      - "VOL1=${VOL1}"
      - "constraint:node==${DATARPM_ZEPPELIN_HOST}"
    volumes:
      - "${VOL1}:${VOL1}:rw"
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "-c", '<some command here>']
```

Comment: I don't know what version of swarm you're using. Post your `docker info`. Also post the code you use to create your container and services.

Comment: Ok, so you're using legacy Swarm, not the new "swarm mode". What's the "network_mode:" set to? Also, the "links:" entry is also legacy stuff that doesn't work for overlay networks, assuming you're using `version: "2"` for the compose file (I can't tell from what you posted since it's just a snippet and not the whole file).

Comment: @Alkaline: network_mode is set as user created overlay network. The purpose of links here is to ensure sequence of start for all containers for the application. I don't need links if we can define sequence in some other way in compose file. You are right , I am using version:2.

Comment: [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/depends-on) can be used for dependencies. `links` are still valid in version 2 config with networks, they just don't do what they use to.

Comment: @Matt I should have written that links are an obsolete feature now. They are simply not doing anything unless used to define an alias (which few people do from what I can see).  `depends_on` can be used for dependencies but keep in mind that they are very limited. They only check that a container is running, not that the app inside the container is ready.

Comment: @SantoshKumar Before going deeper, why are you not using "swarm mode" instead of legacy Swarm?

Comment: @Alkaline , I am planning to start using "Swarm mode", but I doubt it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems [yarn and spark need to be able to see the each other directly on the network](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32851956/1318694). If you could put them on the same overlay network, everything would be able to communicate directly, if not...

#### Overlay

It is possible to route data directly into the overlay network on a Docker node via the `docker_gwbridge` that all overlay containers are connected to *but*, and it's a big *but*, that only works if you are on the Docker node where the container is running.

So running 2 containers on a 2 node [non swarm mode overlay 10.0.9.0/24  network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/#/overlay-networking-with-an-external-key-value-store)...

I can ping the local container on demo0 but not the remote on demo1

```
docker@mhs-demo0:~$ sudo ip ro add 10.0.9.0/24 dev docker_gwbridge
docker@mhs-demo0:~$ ping -c 1 10.0.9.2
PING 10.0.9.2 (10.0.9.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.9.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
docker@mhs-demo0:~$  ping -c 1 10.0.9.3
PING 10.0.9.3 (10.0.9.3): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 10.0.9.3 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Then on the other host the container are reversed but it's still the local container that is accessable.

```
docker@mhs-demo1:~$ sudo ip ro add 10.0.9.0/24 dev docker_gwbridge
docker@mhs-demo1:~$ ping 10.0.9.2
PING 10.0.9.2 (10.0.9.2): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 10.0.9.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
docker@mhs-demo1:~$  ping 10.0.9.3
PING 10.0.9.3 (10.0.9.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.9.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.9.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms
```

So the big issue is the network would need to know where containers are running and route packets accordingly.  If the network were capable of achieving routing like that, you probably wouldn't need an overlay network in the first place.

#### Bridge networks

Another possibility is using a plain bridge network on each Docker node with routable IP's. So each bridge has an IP range assigned that your network is aware of and can route to from anywhere.

```
192.168.9.0/24        10.10.2.0/24
Yarn                  DockerC

             router

10.10.0.0/24          10.10.1.0/24     
DockerA               DockerB
```

The would attach a network to each nodes.

```
DockerA:$ docker network create --subnet 10.10.0.0/24 sparknet
DockerB:$ docker network create --subnet 10.10.1.0/24 sparknet
DockerC:$ docker network create --subnet 192.168.2.0/24 sparknet
```

Then the router configures routes for `10.10.0.0/24` via `DockerA` etc.

This is a similar approach to the way [Kubernetes does its networking](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/networking/).

#### Weave Net

[Weave](https://www.weave.works/products/weave-net/) is similar to overlay in that it creates a virtual network that transmits data over UDP. It's a bit more of a generalised networking solution though [and can integrate with a host network](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/using-weave/host-network-integration/).